# List a number's digits in J

Tags: list, numbers, type-conversion, j

I use the programming language: J.

I want to put all of the digit of a number in a list.

From:

```
12345
```

to:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

What can I do?

Comment: cast the int to string, than in a loop of string length, get each one. Or divide the int to 10 while result is grater than 10.

Comment: How can I append the singles elements to a list?
And with an implicit function?(without the for loop)

Comment: may be your programming language has same methods that splits string into array.

Comment: This is the question: What is this method? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
intToList =: 3 : '((>. 10 ^. y)#10) #: y'
```

This doesn't convert to string and back, which can be potentially costly, but counts the digits with a base-10 log, then uses anti-base (`#:`) to get each digit.

EDIT:

Better, safer version based on Dan Bron's comment:

```
intToList =: 3 : '10 #.^:_1 y'
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nice approach.  Note that the phrase `(>. 10 ^. y)` is has a small flaw when y is 0 or a power of 10: try `intToList 0` or `intToList 1000`.  We can improve the solution by using the inverse of `#:` directly, as in `10 #.^:_1 y` or taking a hint from its implementation and rewriting `intToList` as `3 : '1 + 10 <.@^. 1 >. y'`

Comment: Doesn't support negatives though

Comment: Nor arrays (> scalar). To address that, we might as well take the complete definition suggested by `10&#.^:_1` (as @kaleidic suggested). `10&#. b. _1
($&10@>:@(10&(<.@^.))@(1&>.)@(>./)@:|@, #: ]) :.(10&#.)`.  Or, as a reusable verb: `10&$: : (>:@:<.@:^. 1 >. >./@:|@:,)`

Answer (score 5):

The way I'd write this is

```
   10&#.^:_1
```

which we can see in use with this sentence:

```
   (10&#.^:_1) 123456789 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

That program relies on the reshaping built in to [Base](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d401.htm). It uses the (built-in) obverse of Base as a synonym for [Antibase](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d402.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
intToList =: (".@;"0@":)
```