# Multiply digits of a number in J

Tags: list, numbers, type-conversion, digits, j

I'm trying to multiply the digits of a number in J.

My idea is to convert a number to a list of his digit, and then multiply them.

ps: I am searching for an implicit function.

Update: I found a possible solution, it was easiest that I thought.

Comment: What is [J], what means {":123456789  ... why is it in comments (and why are the comments not closed)? What digits do you mean, and what number?

Comment: And what language is that?

Comment: I forgot the tag, J is a programming language: http://www.jsoftware.com/

Comment: People, please stop closing questions if you've never heard of the subject.

Comment: I think the word you want is "tacit" (rather than "implicit.") http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/intro19.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in another my question: [List a number's digits in J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677142/list-a-numbers-digits-in-j/17688893#17688893)

So, I just need to do:

```
intToList =: (".@;"0@":)
*/(5{.(intToList 123456789))
```

Comment: In these sentences the parentheses are all unnecessary, but they do no harm. I assume you included them because they help you be sure of the arguments to each verb. That's sound practice when beginning to write in J.

Comment: Yes, I am just a beginner. But I love this language most of any others, and by time I will become more efficient. :)